# Express.js middleware and bootstrap application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I’m currently working on a nodeJS app that’s need to check some hardware and software requirements at bootstrap before starting to expose an express API.

The issue that I’m facing with express is that it need a HTTP request to trigger an action, however my bootstrap step do not require a request as it is an autonomous server side routine executed at each start of the app.

For now, I just made my bootstrap process a node module, require it and execute it before calling the express app instantiation. However, I feel this way not that clean.

If anyone can help, it would be wonderful :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the javascript nature, you can always run async task before doing something.

```js
// checlForMinimalRequirements.js
function checkForMinimalRequirements() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) {

    // this is just an async mock
    setTimeout(() => {
      return Math.random() > 0.5 ? resolve() : reject();
    }, 2000);
  });
}


// index.js

import express from 'express';
import {checkForMinimalRequirements} from 'checkForMinimalRequirements';

Promise
  .resolve(checkForMinimalRequirements())
  .catch(() => {
    console.error('Missing Minimal Requirements');
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    const app = express();

    return express.listen(/**/)
  })
;
```

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I do for now except that I use async/await :D

Comment: Oh and BTW, does import statement works natively on Node 8.x series without requiring any transpiler like babel etc?

Comment: this should be a different question but, in the end, no, `node 8` doesn't support modules.

Comment: Yeah I know but as you used ES style module import :D

Thanks a lot for your clear answers and taking time for my question :D

Comment: @DrI this is a well-made article: [`What's new`](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-node8-and-npm5)

Comment: Thank you very much, that’s indeed really interesting. I find out a medium article claiming that too but as it was more than 6 months old and that JS/NodeJS is evolving super fast, I wasn’t sure.

Answer (score 1):

> For now, I just made my bootstrap process a node module, require it
>   and execute it before calling the express app instantiation. However,
>   I feel this way not that clean.

Why shouldn't it be clean? In fact, this is very clean.

Comment: Well, I thought it was not that clean as express is able to mount apps using either:

New instances or Router middleware.

The issue here is that my core app is providing this bootstrap function plus some regular non solicited heartbeat checks and some inventory/discovery that are autonomous and express doesn’t seems to be made for such autonomous work.

Comment: honestly, express doesn't really care when you require a module before the app definition (or after the app definition, but I guess it should still be before app.listen()) and invoke what you required.